# DRF Django - make routable reverse foreign key relationship data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-nested-routers

I have the following models

```
# filename - stocks.models
class Stock(models.Model):

    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    exchange = models.CharField(default="", max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(default="", editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.ticker
        self.slug = slugify(value, allow_unicode=True)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "stock"
        verbose_name_plural = "stocks"
        ordering = ["ticker"]

# filename - prices.models

from viewflow.fields import CompositeKey


class StockPrice(models.Model):
    id = CompositeKey(columns=["ticker_id", "date"])
    ticker = models.ForeignKey(
        "stocks.Stock", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="stocks"
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    open = models.FloatField()
    high = models.FloatField()
    low = models.FloatField()
    close = models.FloatField()
    adj_close = models.FloatField()
    volume = models.FloatField()
```

the following views

```
class StockViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Stock.objects.all()
    queryset = queryset.prefetch_related("stocks")
    serializer_class = StockSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = "ticker"
    lookup_field = "ticker__iexact"

    # override create method to include many=True
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            data=request.data, many=isinstance(request.data, list)
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(
            serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers
        )

#filename prices.views
class StockPriceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = StockPrice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StockPriceSerializer
```

and the following routers

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r"stocks", stock_views.StockViewSet, basename="stocks")

stockprice_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r"stocks", lookup="stocks")
stockprice_router.register(r"price", price_views.StockPriceViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls)),
    path("", include(stockprice_router))
]
```

the router is from `drf-nested-routers`.  How can I set up a url such as `localhost:8000/stocks/appl/price/` that will show the reverse foreign key data ( `models.StockPrice` ) for specifically that stock aapl.

currently when I access `localhost:8000/stocks/appl/price` I get a view on all the stock prices together.

Comment: Can you show `StockPriceViewSet`?

Comment: @bdbd I added in the StockPriceViewSet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case override `get_queryset` to filter out the objects that the nested viewset will work on, based on the selected stock ticker so:

```
class StockPriceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = StockPrice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StockPriceSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        ticker = self.kwargs.get('stocks_ticker')
        if ticker:
            queryset = queryset.filter(ticker__ticker=ticker)
        return queryset
```

The above is if `StockPriceViewSet` can be used as a non-nested viewset. But if `StockPriceViewSet` is only nested on `StockViewSet`:

```
class StockPriceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = StockPriceSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return StockPrice.objects.filter(ticker__ticker=self.kwargs['stocks_ticker'])
```

Comment: I cannot get the PK to work on the urls.  when I lookup `localhost:8000/stocks/aapl/price/0` it returns detail not found ? I would expect it to return the first record based on the column id, any clue why ?

Comment: Hmm does the `StockPrice` object with id 0 belong to `aapl` stock?

Comment: You can only use the pk for price if it matches anything that `StockPrice.objects.filter(ticker__ticker=self.kwargs['stocks_ticker'])` returns, otherwise you will get 404

Comment: All fields i thought automatically have an id created by Django.

Comment: Yes they do, but that id should also be present in `StockPrice.objects.filter(ticker__ticker=self.kwargs['stocks_ticker'])`. Meaning the stock ticker "owns" the stock price